# pgfplot fails to plot large data file by pdflatex and lualatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I have a [big data file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ahthsev5X2HBhLFniih3GGGsZyXLMw) which have 1024*400 points. I can't plot it using pdflatex, so I use lualatex. But I've got nothing but "compile timeout":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3 [
surf,
mesh/ordering=y varies,
] table {pu1pr2raw.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't know why.

By the way, I use overleaf.

Comment: if you ran latex locally you could leave it running as long as needed. Free online servers protect themselves by stopping the job after a certain time, but do you have to plot that many points can you not sample the file to get a more reasonable plot size?

Comment: I can reduce it's size, but I wonder if there are some other ways to do it. I guess I will encounter more big file in the future, so I ask it.

Comment: the pgfplots manual warns that addplot3 is slow at the best of times  I'm running your data file now (with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}`) and it's not stopped after several minutes so I guess like overleaf I am going to kill the job:-) there is no way that many points can be needed in the visualisation.

Comment: oh no with samples=500 it just finished now after 4 minutes, 37 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With luatex on my machine this takes four and a half minutes which may be too long for overleaf (I don't know) It would be more reasonable to make a smaller sample for plotting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3 [
surf,
mesh/ordering=y varies,
samples=500
] table {pu1pr2raw.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]